# Using hook_query_TAG_alter to add 'OR' queries to EntityFieldQuery

Tags: database

I need to use the OR operator on an EntityFieldQuery which I understand can only be accomplished via addTag and hook_query_TAG_alter.

My query at present:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC');
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'news')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('field_pub_year', 'value', $year, '=');
if(isset($_GET['country_id'])){
    $country = $_GET['country_id'];
    $query->fieldCondition('field_related_country', 'target_id', $country, '=');
}
if(isset($keywords)){
    $query->addTag('search');
}
$result = $query->execute();
```

Without much more than a rudimentary knowledge of Drupal, I would expect that the following function, inserted into my template, might work:

```
function hook_query_search_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query){
    $or = db_or()
      ->fieldCondition('title', 'value','%'. $keywords .'%', 'LIKE')
      ->fieldCondition('body', 'value','%'. $keywords .'%', 'LIKE');
    $query->condition($or);
}
```

Yet, it seems to do nothing...

I'm having equal luck googling this problem. Appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks.

Update:

I moved the alter function into a module and re-wrote it to look like:

```
function modulename_query_search_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query){
    $terms = $query->getMetaData('terms');
    $words = "%".$terms."%";
    $or = db_or()->condition('body', $words, 'LIKE')->condition('title', $words, 'LIKE');
    $query->condition($or);
}
```

but I now get an `unknown column body` error.  Removing that condition works correctly and results are filtered by title field. Not sure what the deal is with that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution to using 'OR' queries with EntityFieldQuery:

The query, note the addTag() and addMetaData():

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC');
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'news')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
if(isset($keywords)){
    $query->addTag('search');
    $query->addMetaData('terms', $keywords);
}
$result = $query->execute();
if(isset($result['node'])){
    $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
} else {
    $nids = array();
}
$news = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

Then, within a module or something, the hook_query_TAG_alter looks like:

```
function MODULENAME_query_TAGNAME_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query){
    $terms = $query->getMetaData('terms');
    $words = "%".$terms."%";
    $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_subtitle', 's', 'node.nid = s.entity_id');
    $or = db_or()->condition('s.field_subtitle_value', $words, 'LIKE')->condition('title', $words, 'LIKE');
    $query->leftJoin('field_data_body', 'b', 'node.nid = b.entity_id');
    $or->condition('b.body_value', $words, 'LIKE');
    $query->condition($or);
}
```

Above example shows how to join custom field tables and query them using 'OR' along with title and body fields.

Answer (score 0):

You want `hook_entity_query_alter`, your function signature is broken.

Also it's considered bad practice to use `$_GET` directly.

Comment: ..but I only want to alter the query when a particular tag is present.